# How do I get data from the async/await function before rendering out the UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, asynchronous, es6-promise

I am working out on Github API and using an async/await function to get a list of user's repository.

The problem I am facing is, I am using a `Dropdown component` where I have to provide an array full of repo list which will work as a dropdown, and that array data is coming from the async/await function.

```
  const list = []

  async function fetchRepos() {
    await octokit.repos
      .listForUser({
        username: 'abhinav-anshul',
      })
      .then((details) => list.push(details.data[0].name))

    console.log('List Array', list)
    console.log([...list])
  }
```

Therefore, the UI renders before the function gets executed, and the `items array` turns out to empty.

```
    <>

        <DropDown items={[...list]} placeholder='Select a Repository' />

    </>
```

I am using the `spread operator` to get data in my `Dropdown component`

How do I make sure that I do get data in the items prop from the async-await function, I believe the function cannot be synchronous as well since it is handling the API request. What could be a good strategy for this problem?

Any help is really appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: I would use [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html), since you don't have data there is no need to render, or you can display a loading text or preloader.

Comment: Is `console.log('List Array', list)` and `console.log([...list])` disaplying data properly?

Comment: @palaѕн Yes, it is displaying data correctly

Comment: @ROOT Even, in that case, I would get a loading text, and it would stop at that even if the function ran in the background

Comment: What is your requirement here?

Comment: @palaѕн I am using Github's octokit which list out a user's list of repo. and for the UI I am using `Aragon UI`, I have a component called `Dropdown` which needs an array, and I am getting data for the array from  my function

Comment: You can bring reactivity into React with `this.state` or `useState()` There are so many tutorials out there regarding it. Have you tried to look into that option?

Comment: I have tried `useState` option, I do not quite understand, even if I use `useState` how will the `return` know if the `useState()` has been populated or not with the function and React will re-render the UI

Answer (score 0):

You could initialise your list data with a falsy value, say null and use a ternary operator to stop the Dropdown UI from rendering until your API call finishes executing and populates your list data with the array. This would be 'truthy' value and then your Dropdown could be rendered.

Comment: Even in that case, `return` won't keep on checking the if the async/await has resolved or not in the background if I am not wrong

Comment: Store your list data in a state. That way when it updates the entire block under render would be run again.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use `useState` and `useEffect` to achieve this if you are using hooks based components. It will look something like this

```js
const [list, setList] = useState([]);

async function fetchRepos() {
  await octokit.repos
    .listForUser({
      username: 'abhinav-anshul',
    })
    .then((details) => {
      setList((prevState) => {
        prevState.push(details.data[0].name);
        return prevState;
      });
    });

  console.log('List Array', list);
  console.log([...list]);
}

useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    await fetchRepos();
  })();
}, []);
```

Comment: do you mind creating a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io)?

Comment: It is difficult to create codesandbox, as it has lots of dependencies. I have created a github gist for this file https://gist.github.com/abhinav-anshul/21c445efeeb7b08e3b057ba379f6a3e9

Comment: For the UI components you might want a look at the library https://ui.aragon.org/drop-down/

Comment: The UI looks like this https://ibb.co/FhPjsNB and when the import button is clicked, there is a sidepanel which further lists repos in the dropdown https://ibb.co/X4PzY2w

Answer (score 0):

Can try below solution

```
const [isShowDropdown, setDropdown] = useState(false);
 const list = []

  async function fetchRepos() {
    await octokit.repos
      .listForUser({
        username: 'abhinav-anshul',
      })
      .then((details) => list.push(details.data[0].name))
    setDropdown(true)
    console.log('List Array', list)
    console.log([...list])
  }
```

Render dropdown like this

```
 <>

        {isShowDropdown?<DropDown items={[...list] || [] } placeholder='Select a Repository' />:null}

    </>
```

Comment: This does not work, I am getting the following error `items.map` is not a function. Perhaps it is the reason how the Dropdown library has been defined. It needs to map over string. Please refer to this https://ui.aragon.org/drop-down/

Comment: Try this    items={[...list] || [] }

Comment: This vanishes my `Dropdown component` but when the function ran (after a button click), the dropdown component appears with no data. However, the `console.log([...list])` in the function shows the data in the component correctly.

Comment: I have created a github gist for the whole file https://gist.github.com/abhinav-anshul/21c445efeeb7b08e3b057ba379f6a3e9 this could be helpful

Comment: Try with pre-defining some values in array. And check will it work or not as expected

Comment: list.push(details.data[0].name) --> Is same as your pre-defined data?

Comment: Meanwhile you can assign pre-defined data initially to [] and then in async success can assign with exact data and then check.